# How to set file properties 7zS.sfx self extracting executable

Tags: 7zip, sfx, file-properties

Is it possible to set the file version property on an exe that was created from 7zS.sfx?  It seems the default implementation is to tag the exe with the properties of the 7zS.sfx.exe (see below)

[image]

Comment: This is an issue I am trying to fix myself. It looks like it's not possible to have file details that are custom according to the documentation, but I'm still looking around

Comment: have you found a workaround to change file properties?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. you can change the icon and metadata of the created exe file. You need to have a **resource editor** for this. I recommend using [Resource Hacker™](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

**1.** After downloading and installing (both installer and portable options available), run the the software and open your exe file which was created using 7z sfx.

**2.** Go to 'version info' tab in the left side tree view and change required information.

**3.** Compile script (F5) and save/save as the new exe file.

[image: screenshot for help]

Now you can see, exe metadata has been changed.

[image: screenshot for help]

**Detailed information** on how to use resource hacker™, can be found on the official website.